# xsd and xml validation

Tags: xml, xsd

I have problem validating xml and xsd. Im getting this error from xsd schema.

> src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'urn:id'. It was detected
>   that 'urn:id' is in namespace
>   'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1', but components from this
>   namespace are not referenceable from schema document
>   'virtual://server/schema.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace,
>   perhaps the prefix of 'urn:id' needs to be changed. If this is the
>   correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to
>   'virtual://server/schema.xsd'

And in xml schema I found also this error.

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'xs:schema'. No child element is expected at this point.

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<AddCustomerNotesByExtIDResult>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Status">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StatusCode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <NewDataSet>
      <Status diffgr:id="Status1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
        <Description>Customer Notes added successfully</Description>
      </Status>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</AddCustomerNotesByExtIDResult>
```

And this is my xsd file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="NewDataSet">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Status">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="StatusCode"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Description"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute ref="urn:id" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="urn:rowOrder" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="AddCustomerNotesByExtIDResult">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>
            <xs:element ref="urn:diffgram" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all very odd. You seem to have two versions of the schema, one embedded in your XML document, and one free-standing; and they are different!

I guess we should ignore the one that's embedded in the XML, because there's no evidence it is actually being used for validation.

So you're actually validating the `AddCustomerNotesByExtIDResult` element, and the schema says it should have this content model:

It's defining the content of both elements (xs:schema and urn:diffgram) by reference to declarations in a different namespace, but a schema is not allowed to contain references to declarations in a different namespace unless a schema for that namespace is imported using an `xs:import` declaration. Without such an `xs:import`, the schema is incomplete and invalid.

Another minor observation:

```
<xs:attribute ref="urn:id" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>
<xs:attribute ref="urn:rowOrder" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"/>
```

Now, it's perfectly legal to have two attribute declarations using the same namespace prefix to refer to different namespaces, but it's pretty unorthodox and pretty confusing, and all leads to a general conclusion that this whole thing has been put together without very much understanding of what it all means.